# Setting up a second Homestead Laravel app

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I've been trying to set up a second Laravel 5 app on my local Homestead space. I have been following the instructions from the [official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead) and from [this blog](http://moofy.me/blog/creating-additional-homestead-applications/). (Although I have had to use the specific ID of the provision in order to get the vagrant provision command to work.)

My YAML file looks like this:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\Users\Lisa\Documents\Homestead
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/larapipeline/public
    - map: tinkertower.app
      to: /home/vagrant/code/tinkertower/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

My hosts file looks like this:
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    192.168.10.10  homestead.app
    192.168.10.10  tinkertower.app

I THINK that having gone the provisioning and all that jazz, this should be setting up a starter Laravel app in the tinkertower folder, and that pointing to tinkertower.app should work. The tinkertower folder is empty, however, and trying to visit the site gives me a "server not found," as it's trying to find www.tinkertower.app. I can still get to the homestead.app site. I tried the "serve" command while sshed into homestead, but it didn't make any difference.

So, the questions:
1. Should these steps have added a clean version of Laravel into the tinkertower folder? If not, am I just supposed to grab a new version from Github?

2. Am I missing something that should get the tinkertower.app link working? I don't know enough to know if the fact that both sites have the same IP address is a problem nor how to fix it, nor if I'm missing something else. (After all, if I go to the IP address 192.168.10.10 directly, I get to the first app.)

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1**

Updated YAML file:
    ---
    ip: "192.168.10.10"
    memory: 2048
    cpus: 1
    provider: virtualbox

```
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\Users\Lisa\Documents\larapipeline
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/larapipeline
    - map: C:\Users\Lisa\Documents\tinkertower
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/tinkertower

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/larapipeline/public
    - map: tinkertower.app
      to: /home/vagrant/code/tinkertower/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Hosts file:
    # Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
    #
    # This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
    #
    # This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
    # entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
    # be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
    # The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
    # space.
    #
    # Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
    # lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
    #
    # For example:
    #
    #      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
    #       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.10.10   tinkertower.app
192.168.10.10   homestead.app
```

Comment: Something doesn't seem right, looks like your trying to set your Homestead configuration directory as a website. What is homestead.app supposed to be?

Comment: homestead.app is my first Laravel site. On my computer, it resides in this folder: C:\Users\Lisa\Documents\Homestead\larapipeline

Comment: Perfect, I'm here to help you out, give me a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in your homestead.yaml file.

```
folders:
    - map: C:\Users\Lisa\Documents\Homestead\larapipeline
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/larapipelin
    - map: C:\Users\Lisa\Documents\Homestead\tinkertower
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/tinkertower

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/larapipeline/public
    - map: tinkertower.app
      to: /home/vagrant/code/tinkertower/public
```

Don't forget to edit your hosts file. Now run `vagrant up --provision`, or `vagrant reload --provision`.

## Edit:

Fixed case sensitivity issue on this line.

```
    - map: tinkertower.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/tinkertower/public
```

## Edit 2:

Sorry another mistake :)

You should put your websites into the same directory your Homestead config directory is in.

```
+ Documents
|
| --- Homestead
|
| --- larapipeline
|
| --- tinkertower
```

So all three folders, `larapipeline`, `tinkertower`, and `Homestead` should be in `Documents` directory.

Anyways final code here (hopefully no more mistakes by me):

```
folders:
    - map: C:\Users\Lisa\Documents\larapipeline
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/larapipelin
    - map: C:\Users\Lisa\Documents\tinkertower
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/tinkertower

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/larapipeline/public
    - map: tinkertower.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/tinkertower/public
```

Your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 homestead.app
127.0.0.1 tinkertower.app
```

## Edit 3:

You have a case sensitivity issue. I fixed it, just copy and paste these two lines in the correct place.

```
- map: tinkertower.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/tinkertower/public
```

Change your hosts file, just do it and ask questions later.

```
# 127.0.0.1      localhost you don't need this line
127.0.0.1   tinkertower.app
127.0.0.1   homestead.app
```

**Don't forget to move your actual folders to the correct place**

Comment: I have updated the .yaml file and did vagrant reload --provision, but I am seeing the same issue of tinkertower.app not showing up. My host file is like this:

127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.10.10   homestead.app
192.168.10.10   tinkertower.app

Comment: Your host file should look like this: `127.0.0.1 homestead.app` and `127.0.0.1 tinkertower.app`

Comment: The YAML file has this at the top: 
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
So I'd been using 192.168.10.10 for homestead.app
Changing it to 127.0.0.1 means homestead.app still works, but using it for tinkertower.app still gives "server not found."

Comment: Copy and paste your homestead.yaml and your hosts file, add it the the bottom of your question.

Comment: So for kicks and giggles, I've tried commenting out the homestead.app line in the hosts file, assuming that would mean the homestead.app site would stop showing up, but it actually kept resolving. Not sure if that is expected behavior or not. So confused!

Comment: Ok edited, copy and paste now. I also just made last second edits again. Sorry I didn't sleep last night :).

Comment: Thanks so much! The other "small" problem I found was that I was saving hosts.txt, rather than hosts for the hosts file. Fixed that, made your edits, and I'm up and running. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, sorry for all of my mistakes though. Like I said, no sleep haha.